# Sigma-point Kalman filter (CDKF)

Tags: probability, kalman-filter

*I am completely stuck on the below series of questions. Specifically 3/4/5. I know what some of the correct answers are but I do not understand the steps to get there (especially the input matrix X).*

Consider the nonlinear equation y = f(x) = x^2 + 2, where the input x is a Gaussian random variable having mean of 1 and variance of 1. We desire to calculate the statistics of the output variable y using the sigma-point approach, where we use the CDKF parameter values when doing so, and assume that h=sqrt(3).

1. What is the value of α0^(m)​? Enter your answer with two digits to the right of the decimal point.
   *Correct answer = 0.67*
2. What is the value for the input mean x_bar?
3. What is the value for the input covariance Σx_tilda?
4. What is the value you compute for the output mean y_bar?
   *Correct answer = 4*
5. What is the value you compute for the output covariance Σy_tilda?
   *Correct answer = 6*

Comment: Hi there & welcome to StackExchange! A lot of information is missing from your question, such as: What is a CDKF? It's certainly not an abbreviation for Sigma-point KF. How are the sigma points chosen? What are the formulae for the posterior mean and covariances in your filter? What are h, alpha0^(m), and any of the other variables you mention? Also, per your question, the input mean is 1, so your "correct" answer to question 2 is surely not correct.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. CDKF stands for "central difference Kalman filter". As a reference the lecture is based on these notes (page 1371): http://mocha-java.uccs.edu/dossier/RESEARCH/2006jps2-.pdf

Comment: My thought that x_bar = 3 is based on the hint in this quiz where the set X = {3.0, 9.464, 2.536}. However I am confused about this question so this assertion could be wrong (I edited my original question). The answers for (1), (4) and (5) have been confirmed correct even though I have no idea how this works.